# How do I sort an array by the first character in the string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How do I sort this array?

Input: `['sfr2ta', '2ab', 'bbb1ddd']`

Output: `['bbb1ddd', 'sfr2ta', '2ab']`

Comment: What is the criteria for sorting it that way?

Comment: string that contains letters in the first position will be prioritise first @Abion47

Comment: Sorry, didn't fully read the question. In which way would you like to order your characters? The conventional ascii ordering puts "2" before "b" (as in, in JavaScript "2" < "b").

Comment: How is sorting based on the first character different from sorting based on the whole strings? Do you want the sort to deliberately ignore everything except the first character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort it by the first **charachter** then the output should be like this: ['2ab', 'bbb1ddd', 'sfr2ta'].

But if you want to sort it that letters come before nubmers, then you write something like:

```js
    l = ['sfr2ta', '2ab', 'bbb1ddd'];
    
    lNums = []

    lStrs = []

    for( let s of l ) {
        if(s[0] >= 0 && s[0] <= 9){
            lNums.push(s);
        }
        else {
            lStrs.push(s);
        }
    }
    lNums.sort();
    lStrs.sort();
    l = lStrs.concat(lNums);
    console.log(l)
```

```
output: [ 'bbb1ddd', 'sfr2ta', '2ab' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want zero length strings to act (`""`), this should work:

```
function sortByFirstCharacter(arr) {
    arr.sort((lhs, rhs) => {
        if(lhs === rhs) return 0;
        if(lhs === "") return -1;
        if(rhs === "") return +1;
        return (
            lhs[0] < rhs[0] ? -1
            : lhs[0] > rhs[0] ? +1
            : 0
        );
    });
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the string that contains letters in the first position needs to appear first. the code will put 2ab as the first

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with sort:

```js
var s = ['sfr2ta', '2ab', 'bbb1ddd'];

var result = [...s.filter(n=>!Number(n[0])).sort((a,b)=>a[0].localeCompare(b[0])), ...s.filter(p=>Number(p[0]))];

console.log(result);
```